# Why do we need the definition of family in Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working through Halmos' Naive Set Theory slowly. One thing that stumbles me at the moment is - why do we need to define *family*? In the opening paragraph of section 9 the author says that

> There are occasions when the range of a function is deemed to be more important than the function itself...

But I'm not seeing how this lead to the generalization of communicative and associative laws for set union and intersection operations; also, why do we need to care about finding another generalization of Cartesiann products for a family of sets?

I'm sorry if my question is extremely naive, but, as I'm still learning, the answer to this question is not very evident for me.

Comment: Sometimes a set of reals is more important than the sequence enumerating it.

Comment: Since in the quote you gave there is no mention of family, the question evaporated.

Comment: It is difficult to answer "why do we need such-and-such" questions. If you say something about what you imagine we could do _instead_ you can ask a "why do we do such-and-such and not this-and-that" question instead; such questions can be answered much more specifically. (Sometimes the answer is "we could do this-and-that instead quite fine; it is mostly a historical accident that textbooks usually phrase it as such-and-such").

Comment: @HenningMakholm Uh, that said, can you give me just one elementary example in which an important concept cannot be elegantly introduced without first defining what a family is. It will be immensely helpful!

Comment: @Macrophage: Don't bother pinging me if you haven't read my comment.